# How to avoid re-importing modules and re-defining large object every time a script runs

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, import, load

This must have an answer but I cant find it. I am using a quite large python module called quippy. With this module one can define an intermolecular potential to use as a calculator in ASE like so:

```
from quippy import *
from ase import atoms
pot=Potential("Potential  xml_label=gap_h2o_2b_ccsdt_3b_ccsdt",param_filename="gp.xml")
some_structure.set_calculator(pot)
```

This is the beginning of a script. The problem is that the `import` takes about 3 seconds and `pot=Potential...` takes about 30 seconds with 100% cpu load. (I believe it is due to parsing a large ascii xml-file.) If I would be typing interactively I could keep the module imported and the potential defined, but when running the script it is done again on each run.

Can I save the module and the potential object in memory/disk between runs? Maybe keep a python process idling and keeping those things in memory? Or run these lines in the interpreter and somehow call the rest of the script from there?

Any approach is fine, but some help is be appreciated!

Comment: How often are you calling the script? If you have sufficient RAM, your OS will cache the module files used during `import`. If you want to store `pot`, just write it to a file, e.g. using `pickle`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use raw files or modules such as `pickle` to store data easily.

```
import cPickle as pickle
from quippy import Potential
try:  # try previously calculated value
    with open('/tmp/pot_store.pkl') as store:
        pot = pickle.load(store)
except OSError:  # fall back to calculating it from scratch
    pot = quippy.Potential("Potential  xml_label=gap_h2o_2b_ccsdt_3b_ccsdt",param_filename="gp.xml")
    with open('/tmp/pot_store.pkl', 'w') as store:
        pot = pickle.dump(pot, store)
```

There are various optimizations to this, e.g. checking whether your pickle file is older than the file generating it's value.

Comment: I'm gonna try wthis with your code, but i actually just tried with cPickle and i didn't get it to work. But what do you mean with raw files? Saving it as a binary would to the trick, I think, but how?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't get it to work"? It's part of the py2.7 standard library. Raw files are just files to which you write plain strings without any library on top. For example, if `pot` is a float, you could do `store.write(str(pot))` and `float(store.readline().strip())`.

Comment: I was not well formulated. cPickle did not give an error, neither on dumping nor on loading, but when trying to run the loaded potential, I got an error. And looking at the file it was a few bytes, not near the size of the real object.

Comment: What error did you get? What kind of object do you store?

Comment: I didn't get your exact code to work, instead I used the full expressions starting with `with` to dump and load `pot`. I dump, exit the interpreter, reenter the interpreter and load it (together with the usual imports). Then `>>> type(pot)` correctly gives `<class 'quippy.potential.Potential'>` but at the first line using the potential `object.set_calculator(pot)` i get `Segmentation fault` and no more information. I suspect this object can't be pickled.

Comment: @JonatanÖström I'm afraid if the object isn't built properly, you have to try and extract the relevant information yourself. Depending on how it stores its information, this might admittedly be challenging. You might want to open a ticket at the `quippy` project asking for `Potential` to be made pickle'able.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, but I'm interested in alternatives. You can divide the script into two parts:

start.py:

```
from quippy import Potential
from ase import atoms
pot=Potential(...  etc...
```

body.py:

```
for i in range(max_int):
      print "doing things"
# etc...
```

Then enter python interpreter and run the start-script only once but the body as much as needed:

```
me@laptop:~/dir$ python
>>> execfile('start.py')
>>> execfile('body.py')
>>> #(change code of "body.py" in editor)
>>> execfile('body.py') # again without reloading "start.py"
```

So this means a terminal is occupied and the script is affected, but it works.